# How do I make this function return the value I'm looking for?

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, return

I made a function that's meant to count the number of specific chars in a function recursively.

```
public static int countCharInString(String s, char c)
    {

        return countCharInString(s, c, 0);


    }


    public static int countCharInString(String s, char c, int index)
    {
        if(index==s.length())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(s.charAt(index) == c)
        {
            return 1 + countCharInString(s, c, index+1);
        }
        if(s.charAt(index)!=c)
        {
            return countCharInString(s, c, index+1);
        }

    }
```

How can I put a return statement at the end of the function that'll return the whole number I "counted" inside the function?

Comment: what is the point of your first method?

Comment: also - why use recursion? is this a requirement?

Comment: @sleepToken Yes, it's part of a recursion exercise. I know that memory wise it's worse than running it in a loop, but it's part of the exercise.

Comment: @sleepToken The first function is there to only recieve a String and a Char, I need the 2nd function to add an Index into its input. Is there a way to do it with only 1 function?

Comment: @YonatanRafaely You can do it in one function if, instead of passing an index in, you instead use `substring()` to remove the character you've already checked from the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an extra return statement at the end of the method, the error you're getting is because the compiler isn't convinced that you've got all cases covered.

The easiest fix for this is to simply replace your second comparison against `c` with `else`. Either the character is equal to `c` or it isn't, you don't need a separate check.

e.g.

```
public static int countCharInString(String s, char c, int index) {
    if (index == s.length()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (s.charAt(index) == c) {
        return 1 + countCharInString(s, c, index + 1);
    } else {
        return countCharInString(s, c, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: So that's why I was getting a compilation error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for Loop, If the recursion is needed, Check If 
    Index+1 > s.length()
If this is the Case the recursion should return

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parameter to keep track of your running total. Add a parameter to your function which you'll increment each time you find the character. Then return that number instead of returning 0

Comment: I would generally use a for loop instead of recursion but in this case I had to do it in recursion for exercise. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion here does not make sense to me. The number of characters in a string is going to be `s.length()'.

However, since this is your requirement - I believe you want the count of some character - I recognized this as a classic 're-invent' the wheel program. While I dislike these, the important thing here is to understand what is happening.

Firstly, you don't need a variable for index... because you always set it to 0. So just use 0.

Secondly, let's use `substring` so we don't have to convert to chars and deal with character/String comparisons etc.

```
public static int countCharInString(String s, String c) {
  // This will only happen when the string is empty to begin with, our we're done with recursion. Since we add this to another number in recursion - it works for our purpose
  if (s.length() == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  // If we have a match, increment add add to our recursive sum
  if ((s.substring(0, 1).equals(c))) {
    return 1 + countCharInString(s.substring(1), c);
  }

  // do the final return and invoke recursion
  return countCharInString(s.substring(1), c);
}
```